# not clickable but hoverable pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, css, hover, pseudo-class

I am building a star-rating element using CSS.
I made a set of clickable radio buttons as pink elements. When I click these elements, all elements after them become grey, and all elements before them turn pink.

I want to set a hover on them so I set all the pinks to become grey as I hover.

The problem is that when I hover through the greys , they are already grey so nothing changes.

The solution I am trying is to set five pseudo elements on top of my radio buttons so I can set them to be pink as I hover. These pseudo elements should never be clickable so should never change from gray to pink.

The problem is that I cannot click through the pseudo elements, as they are above.

If I give all the divs for the pseudo elements pointer-events:none, there will be no hover.
If I set a div to wrap these pseudo element's divs, they will hover but clicking is still not possible.

Is there a way to achieve this? A better approach maybe?

here is the code:

```css
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: orchid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.holder-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  
}

input {
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: lightpink;
}

input::before {
  position: relative;
  content: '\2602';
}

.holder::before {
  content: '\2601';
}

input:checked ~ ::before {
  color: #333;
}

.holder:hover ~ ::before {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <input type="radio" data-rate="1" name="rating" class="rating--star" checked/>
  <input type="radio" data-rate="2" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
  <input type="radio" data-rate="3" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
  <input type="radio" data-rate="4" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
  <input type="radio" data-rate="5" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
  
  <div class="holder-wrapper">
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="holder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen => [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/notnishi/pen/eYZNWOp?editors=1111)

I dont understand jquery so if you want to jquery something please, explain what youre doing c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: orchid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    

}

input {
    appearance: none;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: black;
}
input::before {
    position: relative;
    content: "\2602";
    color: black;
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus{
outline:none;
}
input:checked ~ ::before {
    opacity:0.3

}

input:hover ~ ::before {
    opacity:0.2
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" data-rate="1" name="rating" class="rating--star" checked />
<input type="radio" data-rate="2" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
<input type="radio" data-rate="3" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
<input type="radio" data-rate="4" name="rating" class="rating--star" />
<input type="radio" data-rate="5" name="rating" class="rating--star" />

</div>
```

I found a way. I simplified by removing the holder elements, and using opacity values to respond to hover(0.2) and click (0.3).
Strange thing is the ':checked' pseudo-selector actually affects the elements to the right of the mouse. So I worked with that.

I was going to try a JS approach but accessing pseudo elements is a nightmare!

Comment: amazing CSS work. Thank you very much. Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually problem is you trying to achieve this using css that's why you facing this issue, you should do this using javascript or jquery, on hover you should add css on elements on rollout then remove if user clicks then hover event should be holds. This can fix your issue